# Hashing polymorphic type the proper way

Tags: c++, hash, polymorphism, c++14

I have a hash process implemented using [Howard Hinnant's method](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html) (generic hash based on `hash_append` overloads).

The purpose of that method is to create hash of classes in order to "memoize" result of computations (see end of this answer), so I am facing some issue. In particular, consider the following possible `Input` class that needs to be hashed:

```
struct A {
    virtual int do_stuff() const = 0;
    virtual ~A(); 
};
struct B: A {
    int do_stuff() const override { return 0; }
};
struct C: A {
    const int u;
    int do_stuff() const override { return u; }
};

struct Input {
    A const& a; // store a reference to an instance of B or C
};
```

Now, if I want to hash `Input`, I will have something like:

```
template <class HashAlgorithm>
void hash_append(HashAlgorithm& h, Input const& input) {
    hash_append(h, typeid(input));
    hash_append(h, typeid(input.a));
}
```

So I need an overload of `hash_append` for `A`:

```
template <class HashAlgorithm>
void hash_append(HashAlgorithm& h, A const& a) {
    hash_append(h, typeid(a)); 
}
```

The problem here is that depending on the runtime type of `a`, I would need to add extra information to the hash, e.g. for `C` I would need to add `u`.

I thought about the following solutions (and drawbacks):

1. add a virtual method to `A` that returns a specific value that can be added to the `typeid()` hash, but:

   - this means adding a method inside `A` that is not related to the purpose of `A`, thus I don't really like this idea (in particular because I have multiple `A`-like classes);
   - this breaks the concept of `hash_append` since the method will have a unique return type for all inheriting classes.
2. do a bunch of `dynamic_cast` inside `hash_append`:

   - I found this pretty ugly... in particular if I have multiple classes similar to `A`;
   - this is error-prone: if someone adds a new children of `A` and do not add a dynamic_cast inside `hash_append`.

**Is there a way to hash a polymorphic type, without having to modify the type itself or rely on a bunch of `dynamic_cast`?**

---

The final goal of this is to be able to memoize results of some heavy functions. Let's sketch the basic structure of my application:

```
struct Input { };
struct Result { };

Result solve(Input const&);
```

The `solve` function is computationally-heavy, so I want to save the results of previous computation in file using hash of `Input`s, e.g. something like:

```
// depends on hash_append
std::string hash(Input const&);

Result load_or_solve(Input const& input) {
    auto h = hash(input);
    Result result;
    if (exists(h)) { // if result exists, load it
        result = load(h);
    }
    else { // otherwize, solve + store
        result = solve(input);
        store(h, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The `load` and `store` methods would load and store results from files, the goal is to memoize solutions between different runs.

If you have suggestion on how to memoize these results without having to deal with the above issues, I'll be glad to read them.

Comment: You can use double dispatching within the `hash_append` version of `A` and dispatch the request to the proper versions for `B` and `C` when you got the type back, but I don't think that's exactly what you are looking for. Have you considered it? The drawback is that you must add boilerplate to those classes to accept a visitor. If it can work for you, I can put the comment in a more detailed answer.

Comment: @skypjack I'm sorry I do not fully understand what you mean - could you write a small example to illustrate your meaning?

Comment: I mean something [along this line](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1b5c249535f7590). That's not a working example but you should get the idea. Unfortunately your example code lacks a lot of code to be able to pack a concrete example, I'm sorry. And of course, `HashVisitor` can be _simplified_ (at least, designed so that you don't have to modify it each time you define a new type) by using variadic templates and direct inheritance, but the way I defined it should be easier to understand.

Comment: @skypjack Thanks for the example. That's an interesting idea, at least it removes the second drawbacks of my first idea. The way you wrote it, it seems pretty robust (if I add a new class `D`, this won't compile unless I add `D` to the visitor), but would it be possible to simplify `HashVisitor` without losing that robustness? Because if I remove this robustness, this looks similar to the `dynamic_cast` version.

Comment: Let me rework it a bit and put it in an answer, if you find it a viable solution.

Comment: Is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b97c98c08d9d5ce4) closer to what you are looking for? Again, I didn't test it, it's how it came up out of my mind. Anyway it should be clear enough to a skilled user like you. Now `HashVisitor` isn't bound anymore to the actual types and still pretty robust, for it strongly depends on the `Visitor` interface and the lambdas you used to initialize it. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @skypjack Thanks, I'll check how this fit in my project tomorrow, but this is already interesting, so if you want to put an answer I'll at least upvote it!

Comment: Yeah, sure. Even if you don't upvote it, it could be of interest for future readers. I'm putting it in an answer in a while. Hope it works for your case anyway. Let me know, I'm just curious now. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use double dispatching within the `hash_append` version of `A` and forward the request to the proper version (that is the one either for `B` or `C`). The drawback is that you must add boilerplate to those classes to accept a visitor and I cannot say if it's acceptable for you.
Here is a bunch of code that should illustrate the idea:

```
struct B;
struct C;

struct Visitor {
    virtual void visit(const B &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(const C &) = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename... O>
struct HashVisitor: T, HashVisitor<O...> {
    template<typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, U>::value> tryVisit(const U &u) {
        T::operator()(u);
    }

    template<typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same<T, U>::value> tryVisit(const U &u) {
        HashVisitor<O...>::visit(u);
    }

    void visit(const B &b) override { tryVisit<B>(b); }
    void visit(const C &c) override { tryVisit<C>(c); }
};

template<>
struct HashVisitor<>: Visitor {};

template<typename... F
auto factory(F&&... f) {
    return HashVisitor<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<F>(f)...};
}

struct A {
    virtual void accept(Visitor &) = 0;
    virtual int do_stuff() const = 0;
    virtual ~A();
};

struct B: A {
    void accept(Visitor &v) override { v.visit(*this); }
    int do_stuff() const override { return 0; }
};

struct C: A {
    const int u;
    void accept(Visitor &v) override { v.visit(*this); }
    int do_stuff() const override { return u; }
};

template <class HashAlgorithm>
void hash_append(HashAlgorithm &, const B &) {
    // do something
}

template <class HashAlgorithm>
void hash_append(HashAlgorithm &, const C &) {
    // do something
}

template <class HashAlgorithm>
void hash_append(HashAlgorithm &h, const A &a) {
    auto vis = factory(
        [&h](const B &b){ hash_append(h, b); },
        [&h](const C &c){ hash_append(h, c); }
    );

    a.accept(vis);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I think this is the best answer if I want robustness, i.e. not having a type with a non-implemented hash method. Unfortunately, I have to take the opposite direction, i.e. a less robust method (at compile time) but with less constraints: typically, I cannot forward-declare the classes before the visitor, and I still would like to separate the hashing process from the class themselves. I am trying to implement something that would let me add custom runtime dispatch after declaring the classes (I am a bit stuck at the time, might open another question soon... ).

Comment: Let me know and I'll try to give you a response if possible.

Comment: It's here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837117/storing-various-tuples-and-applying-templated-functor-on-them

Comment: @Holt Just seen, sorry, I'm on vacation. You deleted it a few hours ago anyway. I'm sorry if I'm late. :-(